# Check if a field is empty

Tags: 7, entities

How to you check that a field is empty, when you have the $node object?.

I found this as possible solution:

```
$field = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_post_image');
```

I can check now:

**UPDATE**.Ups! This not reliable, althought I promise that it worked for me yesterday.

```
isset($field);
```

but I wonder if there is a better way.

Enlighten me

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you read up on [the documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.module/function/field_get_items/7) the function returns `FALSE` if there is no data. `isset()` would actually fail because you are assigning `FALSE` to the variable so it's actually been set to something. The correct syntax would be:

```
$field = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_post_image');
if ($field) {
   //Do something with the field
}
else{
   //There are no results
}
```

Comment: It seems this is the best way. If it's empty will return FALSE, if has any data it will return an array, so there is no worry that $field evaluates to FALSE in case of number fields 0, etc.

Comment: This did not work for me because it returned the default value when nothing was set.

Comment: @Sam152 Thanks! This worked great for when I was logged in, but when I am logged out it is not showing anything. Is there a reason for that and any solution?

Comment: Hi Dan. Being logged in shouldn't have any impact on the above code. Perhaps you are using devel to debug a variable and anon users don't have "access developer information"?

Comment: This is the wrong way of checking if a field is empty, you should use the approach described with calling the hook_field_is_empty defined by the module implementing the field, see the post by kiamlaluno.

Answer (score 8):

You could use the following snippet to verify if a field is empty.

```
$info = field_info_field($field_name);
$function = $info['module'] . '_field_is_empty';

if (function_exists($function)) {
  $value = field_get_items('node', $node, $field_name);
  $is_empty = $function($value[0], $info);
}
```

This code is safer, as different fields are considered empty under different conditions. See, for example, the difference between [file_field_is_empty()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--file--file.field.inc/function/file_field_is_empty/7), [number_field_is_empty()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--modules--number--number.module/function/number_field_is_empty/7), and [taxonomy_field_is_empty()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_field_is_empty/7): `taxonomy_field_is_empty()` checks the *tid* property of the `$item` parameter, while `number_field_is_empty()` checks the *value* property of the same parameter. Custom fields could require a more complex condition to be verified, in order to consider the field empty.

The description for [hook_field_is_empty()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.api.php/function/hook_field_is_empty/7) given in the documentation is the following one:

> Define what constitutes an empty item for a field type.

Comment: I appreciate this answer, but the hook_field_is_empty() seems to go very far. I want to know if the field is really empty. For example number_field_is_empty considers that 0 is also empty. Also I test that you can't apply this function directly if the field is multi-value.

Comment: That is what does empty() when you pass it a variable containing 0, or the string "0"; it could be the field is using a value when it is empty, and invoking hook_field_is_empty() is the only way to know if the field is empty.

Comment: There is a mistake. Should be $function($value[0], $info); See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_is_empty/7.x

Answer (score 3):

#### Drupal 8

If somebody need the same answer in D8, that is what I do to test my field:

```
if ($entity->hasField('field_event_date_start')
  && !$entity->get('field_event_date_start')->isEmpty()) {
  // Do something ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We found the raw value in (`$content['field_name']['#items'][0][value]`), so you can determine if the field is empty or not with the expression

> (!empty($content['field_name']['#items'][0][value]))

where `field_name` matches the name of the desired field.

Comment: No. The "value" key is just a db column name. It can be different depending on the field type. I think the best way - check hook_field_is_empty() (which is required)  as proposed above

Answer (score 0):

If needs to check for a field in a custom webform, or existing form in Drupal 8:

```
if (is_null($form_state->getValue('field_name')[0]['value']) {
    $form_state->setErrorByName('field_name', t('Please select a value'));    
}
```