# How do I check if a field is empty?

Tags: 7, entities

On my views-view-field template, I would like to print out 'field_images' if 'field_cover_image' is empty.

I tried this [solution here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11238/check-if-a-field-is-empty) but it throws me this error message.

> Notice: Undefined variable: node in include() (line 45 of /sites/all/themes/mytheme/templates/views-view-fields--incubator.tpl.php).
>
> EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7539 of /includes/common.inc).

Is there any other ways to check if a field is empty or not?

Thanks!

Comment: please paste your code, what code have you tried?

Comment: This is the code that I tried:
`$field = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_cover_image');
if($field){
     print 'yes there is';
}else{
     print 'no there isn't';
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been awhile but thanks again for sharing your solutions. I ended up using [Views if Empty](http://drupal.org/project/views_ifempty) module and that saves me from creating a views .tpl

Answer (score 1):

You get that error because `$node` is not one of the variables passed to [views-view-fields.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!views-view-fields.tpl.php/7), which receives:

- `$view`: The view in use.
- `$fields`: an array of $field objects.
- `$row`: The raw result object from the query, with all data it fetched.

Basing on the description, `$row` could be used to retried the node object. I cannot tell you the content of that variable, but using [print_r()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) from your template file can help to understand its content.

Comment: Hi, I've tried all three variables ($view, $fields, $row) that you mentioned and there's no error. However, it doesn't seem to be working as one of the entry that has a Cover Image still prints out "no". Here's the code:

`$field = field_get_items('row', $row, 'field_cover_image'); if($field){ print 'yes'; }else{ print 'no'; }`

Answer (score 1):

Use views preprocess API and check if(isset(field['name'])) and then do things as per your needs. Put this in a module to achieve your needs. This will be a long term solution.

Comment: I have 2 entries, 1 without cover image and another one with a cover image. So I tried this code below but on the entry without cover image it still prints out "yes".
`if(isset($fields["field_cover_image"]->content)) {
              print 'yes';
          } else {
     print 'no';
    }`
PS: I'm no programmer. I would be happy if I could use GUI to set things up to achieve this; which is working for some other content type but not for this particular content type.

Comment: I am not sure about all the variables in your code. But i would say there will be a way to differentiate the variable with cover and with out cover image. Put print_r in the module to get the list of variables and then use isset condition. I think you are almost half way done, keep trying.

Comment: I think Gladiator is correct. There must be a way to differentiate the things. Try some other fields instead of the one mentioned above in ur coment.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for this is to add both fields but add field_images first and mark is as 'exclude from display'. Then add the field_cover_image and in the 'NO RESULTS BEHAVIOR' section add the token for field_images (can be found in replacement patterns). Done!