# How to list nodes with at least one field empty?

Tags: 7, entities

Is there any module or built-in function to check if all the node fields are filled with some values, and list nodes that fails this check?

EDIT: In short, I just want to get the list of nodes having any of their field empty.

Comment: Show us your use case. Do you need a list of nodes with empty fields waiting to be filled? Or you want to make all fields required at save? Or what? There are many ways for many needs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if a field is empty](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11238/check-if-a-field-is-empty)

Comment: I just want to get the list of nodes having any of their field empty.

Comment: qasimzee please update your question with information like that, instead of posting it in a comment. @Chapabu in light of OP's comment, it is not a duplicate... well, not of that question anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module.

Create a view, then add a filters  `Content: field_name (empty)` - one for each field. Change operator from `AND` to `OR` and done, you have a list of nodes with at least one field empty.